# VBA code to perform an action on all worksheets and workbooks with unknown names

Tags: excel, vba

I have many reports that all have subtotals in them which I do not need. They are all on a line with a unique number then "Total"(bolded). I am trying to create code that will apply to all of my workbooks as I create new ones that will find and delete any row that has the "Total"(bold) text in it. I know how to apply it to specific workbooks/worksheets with names that I know but do not know how to get it to apply to any worksheet with any name as they come up.

```
    Sub Find_Delete_Total()
    Dim Total_Row As Long
    Dim X As Long

    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


     With Ws
            With Application.FindFormat.Font
                .FontStyle = "Bold"
                .Subscript = False
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            For X = 1 To 10000



        Total_Row = Cells.Find(What:="Total", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Select.Row
                    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

            Next X
        End With
    Next Ws

End Sub
```

Comment: 'to any worksheet with any name as they come up' means all opened workbooks, active worksheets, all worksheets in active workbook or as you open workbooks?

Comment: As new workbooks are created by the report I need to run. Their names and the sheet names change every time I run the report.

Comment: Can I ask why the `For x = 1 to 100000` loop? That seems to be unnecessary overhead here, that looks like it isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: @DavidZemens I was thinking I would have to use a loop to accomplish my goal and the 10k seemed like a number of occurrences that would never be hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're revised code is missing the `End With` which corresponds to the `With ActiveSheet`. Also, change `ActiveSheet` to `Sht`, and *qualify* the appropriate objects in the `Cells.Find`.

I made some revisions which should avoid errors in the event that "total" is not found.

```
Sub Find_Delete_Total()
Dim Total_Row As Long
Dim X As Long
Dim delRow as Range
Dim Sht as Worksheet

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets
    With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Subscript = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Sht
        For X = 1 To 10000
            Set delRow = .Cells.Find(What:="Total", _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=True)
           If Not delRow Is Nothing Then 
               delRow.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
           End If
        Next X
    End With
Next Sht
End Sub
```

Comment: This is working almost correctly. It is now removing all rows which contain the word Total and not taking into account the bold requirement. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: @TonyP Revised to use the optional parameter in your `.Cells.Find`: `SearchFormat:=True`.

Comment: Oddly it no longer deletes any rows now. This answers my original question though and I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: If `SearchFormat` is true, do you not need to specify the format to search for?

Comment: @RGA I'm not sure, but it seems like you would need to,  otherwise what format would it search for if you didn't specify?

Comment: @RGA that was in the code as of last revision yesterday evening. I took it out briefly for a hack/workaround, but put it back a few mins later after I debugged.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
....
Next ws
```

Comment: Replace 'With ActiveSheet' with 'sht.Activate'